# How to open applications like phone dialler on clicking tableview cell ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios10

I am new in iOS development.
I have created a tableview menu which looks something like this :

[image]

Now I want to open the Phone Dialler, Messaging and Email app on cell tap. How to go about it ?

I was something like this ( DOESN'T WORK !!! ) :

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row == 0){
        NSLog(@"Call selected!!");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tell://1234"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    }
    else if (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row == 1){
        NSLog(@"Text Selected!!");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Email Selected!!");
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Note : I am building on iOS 10.2 so methods like openURL are depreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work? is `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` called? Why do you use `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row` when you have the `indexPath` in the parameter? `tell://` vs `tel://`? Did you try by calling `canOpenURL:` first?

Answer (score 1):

You can initiate a call

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html][1]

is not `tell://1234`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tell://1234"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

it is `tel:1234`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1234"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

or use

`telprompt` gives the user a choice to place the call or cancel making the call before the phone dials. The two forward slashes after the colon are optional.

for e.g

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://1234"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

dont forget to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your .plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>tel</string>
 <string>telprompt</string>
</array>
```

for more information you can get the link for [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/)

Comment: You can remove the `//`, just `tel:1234` will work. This is well document in Apples [Phone Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) documentation.